# Oversampling / gridding a 2D histogram

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, astronomy, binning

I've got a numpy 2D histogram that bins data points with two spacial coordinates (x_array and y_array) and averages the values of a third, data_array component within each bin.

The code is as follows:

```
xbins = 240    #image is 240x240
ybins = 240

H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(y_array, x_array, bins=[ybins, xbins], weights=data_array)
count, x, y = np.histogram2d(y_array, x_array, bins=[ybins, xbins])
H/=count     

extent = [yedges[0], yedges[-1], xedges[-1], xedges[0]]
plt.imshow(H, extent=extent, interpolation='nearest')
```

etc.  (The x's and y's are reversed in some places, I know... it's just the way I got it to work).

**What I need to do now is oversample (or grid) this data, i.e. sample a few times with overlapping bins such that the whole sampling moves over, and also up (separately), half a bin-width, to achieve a smoother image.**

I can obviously increase the number of bins to increase the resolution, but that only works to a point... at a certain point there are bins without any data points, as they are distributed randomly.

I've been working on this one for a while and I'm just stumped.  Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Have you tried any kind of interploation? http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html

Comment: I may have been a little unclear on the objective here... interpolation would smooth out the image, but I don't think it'll do the same thing as oversampling.  The objective isn't so much about the smoothing as it is improving the resolution.  I'm trying to map fine-grain features (details smaller than the bin size), and there is a limit where just reducing the bin size is no longer desirable.

Comment: You may have run out of data.  What you are describing is (I think) mathematically equivalent to using interpolation to over sample.

Comment: I still think they're different... with interpolation you're basically inventing values to fill in the gaps.  with oversampling you're sampling the same data several times and adjusting the boundaries of each bin.  They can both achieve higher resolution, but interpolation will smooth over fine-grain details that I'm trying to capture.

(Not trying to argue this, I just would like to keep this thread alive so others might also weigh in).

Comment: If you _really_ want to do this, just pass in list of bins to hist2D with different shifts and then shove the results into a larger array.  However, I think this is verging on data-falsification so your on your own.  I would suggest looking at 1D data and sorting out that over-sampling and linear interpolation do.  Statistically, I think they will be the same (and you shouldn't believe where they are different anyway)